# How can i fix linkedlist using with iterator in Java?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, gethashcode

When create a linkedlist in hash class search method, my iterator does not work with it. What can i use instead of iterator? How can i fix it.

```
public static void search(String keyword){
    String hashString = hash(new String(keyword.toLowerCase()));
    if (maps.containsKey(hashString)) {
        LinkedList<String> list = maps.get(hashString);

        Iterator iter = list.iterator();
        System.out.println("This word has been appeared in following text files: ");
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iter.next() + "");
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No text files includes this word.");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

---

```
package hash;

public class LinkedList<Item> {
Node<Item> first;
Node<Item> last;
int size = 0;

public LinkedList(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
    size = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: This would work fine with the built in linked list.  Why are you building your own, and if you are, why aren't you implementing an iterator?

Comment: I use iterator to find words in txt files but it throws an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `iterator()` method would only exist if you defined it in your class. Since you are defining your own LinkedList class (I assume as coursework since there's already a robust LinkedList class in the standard library), you have to write your own implementation of the Iterator class and return an instance of it in a method of your LinkedList class.